# NodeJS http server not sending entire buffer / fetch not getting entire buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fetch

I'm sending a buffer with a video file in it with `res.end(buffer)` (with the default node http server module). When I print the buffer size in my node program, it gives me a certain number, but in the client, when I print the buffer size, it often gives me a smaller number, and the video in the buffer doesn't play back (sometimes, it does play back, and in this case, the two number match).
Here is the code that gets buffers on the client side :

```
var fetchDataByReference = (reference) => {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({reference})
    }; let url = '/storage';
    return fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(res => {
            var reader = res.body.getReader();
            return reader
                .read()
                .then((result) => {
                    // When I print the result's length, it sometimes doesn't match with the length of the buffer I sent.
                    return result;
                });
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reader.read()` returns stream of data. You need to check the data it has done is positive.

```
function fetchStream() {
  const reader = stream.getReader();
  let charsReceived = 0;

  reader.read().then(function processText({ done, value }) {
    if (done) {
      console.log("Stream complete");
      para.textContent = value;
      return;
    }

    const chunk = value;
    // work with chunk
    return reader.read().then(processText);
  });
}
```

You can read more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader

I will recommend you to use `.json` API instead.

```
fetch(url, {})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

POST:

```
async function post(url = "", data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

post("https://example.com/answer", { answer: 42 }).then((data) => {
  console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `response.json()` call
});
```

Comment: It worked, I just had to make an array of those chunks and create a blob from them !